# Is "introductive" a word? Or should I use "introductory"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I was very surprised when open office's spell check underlined the word *introductive*. I checked a few dictionaries and only a few (including The *Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*, Oxford University Press, 1973) list it as an entry, whereas all contain the word *introductory*. I would like to know if the latter is preferable, since I used the former in an official document, and prefer to stick to it unless there are sound reasons not to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked the BNC and COCA for usage stats in British and American English and found zero for both. Checking Google's NGRAM viewer for these two, back in the early 1800s a few instances of *introductive* are recorded, but *introductory* is common.

There **are** sound reasons not to use *introductive*:

> It's not idiomatic contemporary British or American English
>   It's too unusual not to stand out and appear pretentious
>   It's not a felicitous replacement for *introductory*

Despite its grammaticality, it's a stylistic zit. If you want your prose to be [acned](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acned), then use it. If you want your prose to be smooth and appealing, then use either *introductory* or *prefatory*. I advise this as a writing teacher (40 years) and technical editor.

Comment: Ok, you have convinced me, I will change it to introductory if bureaucracy doesn't get in the way. The word is part of my bachelor thesis title, and I rather carelessly put *introductive* in the english translation of the title. However, the new translation of my transcript of records is independent, so I should be able to get away with the switch. Thank you for your answer and expert opinion, upvoted and accepted!